# How can you search for a specific file in the current directory and its subdirectory in php and once found display the path?

Tags: php

Lets assume that I have a directory "abc" and within this directory I have four sub-directories, and each sub-directory has 5 sub-directories each, now out of these 5 sub-directories one on the directory has a file name test.txt and I want to locate that using php, how will I achieve this ?

Comment: Did you try something ?

Comment: I did not but I am trying to achieve something out of this.

Comment: Your question is unclear.. What exactly are you trying to do?

Answer (score 0):

Although you should try to solve your problem first before coming here for help, there's a pretty good tool that might be helpful in this case. It's called the [Symfony Finder Component](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/finder.html). You can install it through composer and it should quite easily do what you need. Here's an example (tweaking may be required as I haven't tested this exact code)

```
use Symfony\Component\Finder\Finder;

$finder = new Finder();
$files = $finder->in('/path/to/abc')->name('test.txt')->depth('< 3');
foreach ($files as $file) {
    //Your file here
}
```